# CNN: challenge to recognize simple blocks

Tags: computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I would love to obtain insights and perspectives on the following challenge. I am trying to train a CNN to classify images that have a distinct "block" in a different color (please see the example below). The images are 2D arrays (e.g. 20 by 100 pixels) where white is coded as 0, blue is coded as 1 and green as 2.

I am struggling - somewhat to my surprise - to train a network with good performance on these type of images - especially to prevent over-fitting and very poor performance on validation sets when image sizes are getting bigger (e.g. 40 by 100). I am trying to understand / conceptualize what type of CNN structure is needed to recognize these type of features.

I have included my current network structure below - but this structure tends to have mixed performance, and fails or gets very slow when image sizes increases. I presume that the network has to see the entire cyan 'block' from top to bottom to make an accurate classification.

I would love to get thoughts on the best approach to do so. Is the best approach to add more layers to the network? Or work with bigger convolution windows? Or to add more conv. filters to each layer (e.g. from 64 to 96, etc.)? I feel I am doing something wrong on a basic level.

Thoughts and perspectives much appreciated.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))  

opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.001, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

Comment: Just to understand your challenge correctly: You already have your result encoded in your data (any occurence of green pixel = positive(1)). Why do you want to train a neural network rather than simply check for color green in your images?

Comment: Why is the last image negative?

Comment: If the problem is as simple as finding one block in a different color, you probably need very very few filters, such as 1 or 2, and few layers too. This problem is simple enough to solve without a neural network.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This example is a simplified version of a more complex image recognition problem that i am trying to solve. I am trying to start with a stylized simple example. The last image is negative as the block doesnt cover the entire vertical width of the diagram, and is only one pixel wide. I understand that one can hand-code these rules, but i would like to nudge the CNN to extract these features automatically.

Comment: I tried running a network with only 2 layers with few filters (ranging from 2 to 4) - but unfortunately performance was not strong.

Comment: If the condition for pos/neg is if the block touches the outer limits: Have you thought about just looking at the first and last horizontal line? Reducing your data to just the significant parts and thereby reducing noise can very much help the network learning.

Comment: In addition to that: Have you tried to add one more dense layer after your flatten layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to show you two possible problems with your design and some possible solutions:

1. The **receptive field** of your network is too small: Let's analyze your network with respect to the size of the original picture which a filter from a given layer *sees*:

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape)) # RF size = (3, 3)
   model.add(Activation('relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # RF size = (4, 4)
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))

   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3))) # RF size = (6, 6)
   model.add(Activation('relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # RF size = (7, 7)
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))
   ...
   ```

   So the maximal size of a field from with your network is getting a signal is way smaller than a size of your picture (which seems to have the height of 10).

   To overcome this issue - you could increase the filter size in a first layer to have a height equal to a height of your picture (so basically used something equivalent to `1D` convolution).
2. **`Flatten` is a bad idea:** When you use `Flatten` - your network actually takes into account the position of different patterns on your images - so e.g. it needs to discriminate a full block on the left and the full block on the right separately even though that these are the same objects. The best option to overcome this is to use `GlobalMaxPooling2D` which is the best for *detecting* patterns on an image (given that filter size is big enough).